# Any reason to use databindings, triggers and commands - C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay keep in mind I am use to not use these features at all. 
Okay I have started to take a look at databindings and commands, instead of for instance Click methods.

My problem is that I have been looking through examples on both codeproject and msdn, and to me even simple examples, are confusing, because of the following:

- I can't see in which cs-class file the databinding belongs to
- I can't see why triggers for instance, should be placed in the markup parts of once applikation

And then I find it stupid, that for instance Microsoft them self implements a third party library to make there examples, so it is not a "complete" product.

This results in, that I have a hard time seeing any benefits in using databindings, triggers and commands. So are there any real benefints? What are the reasons to use it. 
Because the MSDN states that developers loves it, and I just can't see why. (Might get a lot of down votes for this I assume)

Comment: Are you referring to MVVM? What is this 3rd party lib you mention?

Comment: All examples I have found uses MVVMlight - yes

Comment: You _"have a hard time seeing any benefits in using databindings, triggers and commands"_ just because Microsoft allegedly uses a _"stupid...third party library to make there examples"_.  I suspect some of the database connectors are made by third parties.  Are they _"stupid"_ too?   I have never had a need to use MVVMlight and the samples years ago made no mention of it

Comment: Your question is essentially about [tag:MVVM] - which is a _design pattern_.  Like all patterns no one is forcing you to use it, but your code will arguably suffer in the long term if you do not, especially when you consider WPF was designed with MVVM in mind

Comment: The question is ways too broad. The benefits come in when you have 
a) the need to test your code. the _click handler would always have a particular signature and be implemented on a concrete class -> harder to unit test b) the need to work in a large team of people, where not everyone is a developer - a designer can work in blend on xaml while you're working on the code in VS and these don't need to interact. c) the need to write clean code. Strive for 150 line classes, 6 line methods and achieve good maintainable code.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I do not see mvvmlight as the confusing part - read my question again - I find it stupid that I need it to do it, because I don't with for instance click events

Comment: @zaitsman you actually just answered it :D so thanks

Comment: @zaitsman _" I do not see mvvmlight as the confusing part - read my question again - I find it stupid that I need it to do it,"_ - I still fail to understand why **you think you need to use MVVMlight for WPF**

Comment: @LarsNielsen It took me a while to grok the MVVM pattern myself but once you get the hang of it, it makes things a lot cleaner and easier to handle. For example keeping everything in sync on a multi-tabbed form where you need to handle events triggered by various parts of the UI. The good thing is, you can start out small just using binding and take on commands etc. later on.

Comment: @MickyDuncan when I try to make a RelayCommand, as in done in some of the examples on MSDN, I can't without MVVMlight or something else, and in the example code I download, MVVMLight is include

Comment: @LarsNielsen i'm with you on the mvvm frameworks - i find that hardly any of them provide tangible benefits to the code and the final products. Using some very basic techniques you can reduce the amount of boilerplate very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to ask the same question when I first started XAML development.

Once I got the hang of things, I learned that leveraging this framework resulted in cleaner design.

**DataBinding and Triggers**

The state of your user interface is indirectly bound to your model via view-model. This means that ideally, the state of your UI should automatically reflect your model whenever your model gets updated.

In addition, by using Data Binding and Triggers, the amount of plumbing within your code-behind is dramatically reduced which often results in cleaner code.

The issue with code-behind logic is that it is essentially UI logic that does not isolate behavior. This means that your code-behind class no longer adheres to single-responsibility. Instead, it ends up becoming a God-class and attempts to interrogate its own self regarding its state. Using data binding and triggers alleviates the need to write this plumbing. Again, by using data binding and triggers, your UI should automatically reflect your model whenever your model gets updated.

**Commands**

Commands may not be necessary. However, they appear to be a cleaner solution in regards to separation of concerns. In addition, when commands are used, code-behind plumbing is no longer required.

Furthermore, I try to perceive my view-model as the minimal documentation required for a user interface. Thus, I try to design my view-model to expose only commands and state (i.e. properties) that my view requires in order to be operational.